# TypeError: expect.addSnapshotSerializer is not a function - Jest with styled components

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, styled-components

I have a problem with jest and jest-styled-components.

I am currently using jest 21.2.1 and jest-styled-components 4.9.0 to run my snapshot test. However, when I run all my test jest throws this error message.

[image]

Has anyone had a similar issue and knows how to fix it? I have the feeling that is a dependency issue and I tried different versions with jest but nothing changed. Here is the code for the `PanelView.test.js` :

```js
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import 'jest-styled-components';

import PanelView from '../PanelView';
import * as exports from '../index';


describe('PanelView', () => {
  test('exports', () => {
    expect(exports).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  test('PanelView hidden panels', () => {
    const rendering = renderer.create(
      <PanelView
        visiblePanels={{
          filter: false,
          details: false,
          content: false,
        }}
        filter={ 'test' }
        content={ 'test' }
        details={ 'test' }
      />
    ).toJSON();
    expect(rendering).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  test('PanelView visible panels', () => {
    const rendering = renderer.create(
      <PanelView
        visiblePanels={{
          filter: true,
          details: true,
          content: true,
        }}
        filter={ 'test' }
        content={ 'test' }
        details={ 'test' }
      />
    ).toJSON();
    expect(rendering).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  test('PanelView hidden mobile', () => {
    window.innerWidth = 300;
    const rendering = renderer.create(
      <PanelView
        visiblePanels={{
          filter: false,
          details: false,
          content: true,
        }}
        filter={ 'test' }
        content={ 'test' }
        details={ 'test' }
      />
    ).toJSON();
    expect(rendering).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  test('componentWillReceiveProps', () => {
    PanelView.getHidingDirection = jest.fn(PanelView.getHidingDirection);
    const wrapper = renderer.create(
      <PanelView
        visiblePanels={{
          filter: false,
          details: false,
          content: false,
        }}
        filter={ 'test' }
        content={ 'test' }
        details={ 'test' }
      />
    );
    try {
      wrapper.setProps();
    } catch (error) {
      expect(error).toMatchSnapshot();
    } finally {
      expect(PanelView.getHidingDirection).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }
  });

  describe('getHidingDirection', () => {
    test('right', () => {
      const currentPanels = { filter: false, details: false, content: true };
      const nextPanels = { filter: true, details: false, content: true };
      const hidingPosition = PanelView.getHidingDirection(currentPanels, nextPanels);
      expect(hidingPosition).toBe('right');
    });

    test('left', () => {
      const currentPanels = { filter: false, details: false, content: true };
      const nextPanels = { filter: false, details: true, content: true };
      const hidingPosition = PanelView.getHidingDirection(currentPanels, nextPanels);
      expect(hidingPosition).toBe('left');
    });

    test('error', () => {
      try {
        PanelView.getHidingDirection({}, {});
      } catch (error) {
        expect(error).toMatchSnapshot();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I had the same problem and upgrading jest to the latest version solved it for me, the only weird thing that I see in your code is that `import * as exports`, try renaming that variables as it is a reserved keyword :)